# iOS Background Task Completion Programming

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, multitasking

I'm trying to add support for completing a task after exiting the foreground for my iOS App. All the tutorials I saw on the internet point me to writing something like this in the Application Delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
        background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
            [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
            background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            //DO STUFF IN BACKGROUND HERE
            MyTask *task = [[MyTask alloc] initWithURL:@"http://google.com"];
            [task setDelegate:self];
            [task start];

            [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
            background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        });
    }
}
```

The task is able to start, but after it starts, the next line gets processed and my app is killed. I am able to tell when `MyTask` stops due to a delegate call, but how do I change my program so that the background task gets set to invalid after the delegate gets called. Would I move

```
[application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

to the delegate function, or do I need to do something else.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Guvvy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're already in a background thread per your call to `dispatch_async`. That method will return immediately, but your block will continue to run.

Your problem seems to be that your start method runs another asynchronous process, so that method returns immediately, and your background task is killed before `[task start]` is able to do anything meaningful.

If you go the route of killing `background_task` in your delegate, you'll also have to create an ivar to store `background_task` so your delegate methods can get to it. That seems a little heavy handed.

Since you're already in a background thread, my suggestion would be for you to refactor `[task start]` so it's synchronous. That way, all the meaningful work will be performed before the next line is processed and `background_task` is killed. This seems cleaner, and everything for your background task is nicely wrapped in the block sent to dispatch_async.

Comment: hi @djibouti33 can u plss elaborate what uare trying to say "my suggestion would be for you to refactor [task start] so it's synchronous." . I am using a NStimer call a method after 600 sec . but the bgTask is expired instantly as the app goes background

Comment: the method [task start] was an asynchronous method, which means it returned immediately (before any work was performed), and then the background_task was killed. my making it synchronous, the method would block any other execution until it was complete, and then the background_task could be killed successfully and at the correct time.

Answer (score -2):

You can completely remove following code:

```
[application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

When your task is expired, iOS will call your handlerExpiration method to kill it.
For more information, please visit [Background for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)

Comment: This is plain wrong. If you do not call endBackgroundTask: within the specified time, your app will be completely killed, instead of remaining suspended and "launching" faster in the eyes of the user. See the documentation  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/endBackgroundTask: